# Admin credentials doesn't work in datopian installation of ckan?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ckan

I have been installing *ckan* with *docker* from the page of [datopian-tech](https://tech.datopian.com/ckan/getting-started.html#booting-ckan). The problem I have is in the last part of section *"getting started"*: When I use the credentials given *ckan* says that are bad credentials.

Comment: Does what you are asking have a code solution? If so, give an example of what you have tried to do so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a new account and give it admin rights. After you create a new account use this [command](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/paster.html#sysadmin-give-sysadmin-rights) to promote it to admin. Note that paster command is removed in CKAN2.9 so you will need to check [this guide](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/maintaining/getting-started.html#create-admin-user).